# Configuration of static IP address

Tags: networking, ethernet, interface, ipv4

I used the link to set-up configuration of IP address 
but I got this

```
 Failed to bring up eth0
```

command I used:

```
sudo ifup eth0
```

configuration  is

```
# The primary network interface
 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet static
 address 192.168.1.6
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 192.168.1.1
```

I have this

```
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
```

but network I don't know , and tried them but still same error

Comment: Did you mean `gateway` instead of `address` in that last line?

Comment: don't know if it matters for the problem but eth0 is also misspelled in the `allow-hotplug` line.

Comment: ohh yes i didn't notice that i wrote address instead of gateway , i'll try it now

Comment: still has this RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.

Comment: @ Eddie Dunn i didn't get what you mean sorry ? is there misspelled too ?

Comment: Do `sudo ifup -v eth0` and add the output to your question..

Answer (score 0):

**Static Ip config for eth0**

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.10.33
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.10.255
    network 192.168.10.0
    gateway 192.168.10.254 
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 # Googles DNS name servers
```

**Note:** Make sure that you edit the lines according to your network.

Comment: i will edit the post , but still error

Comment: @Begnnier What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: 14.04 >>>>>>>>>

Comment: Try `ifconfig eth0 down && ifconfig eth0 up`

Comment: SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
and ineternt disconnected "i sent this message by wi-if"

Comment: Do this to restart your networking interfaces `/etc/init.d/networking/restart`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32907/discussion-between-alex-and-begnnier).